# u"'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format i need it to be MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, sqlite, django-models

ValidationError at /uimsapp/employee/19543/

[u"'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/uimsapp/employee/19543/
Django Version:     1.8
Exception Type:     ValidationError
Exception Value:

[u"'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Exception Location:     /home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py in to_python, line 1287
Python Executable:  /home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.15
Python Path:

['/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/src',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odf']

Server time:    Mon, 27 Aug 2018 13:35:37 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
/home/fella/djangoApps/pmo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

                                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
```

Request information
GET

No GET data
POST
Variable    Value
status

u'MALICK SALLAH                                                                        '

dob

u'1990-12-15'

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Please format code in your question, and state the question itself

Comment: You can now check

Comment: Please post the code in question that is causing this problem.

Comment: If your tools need a date to be in a specific (And standard) format, you should use that format.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import datetime

old_date='1990-12-15'
new_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(old_date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Output:
12-15-1990

Comment: Your question is not clear to try to ask a clear question add some code where you are facing problems  e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984689/djnago-filter-query-from-many-to-many-fields